# Everything in the paged scroll view is to the right

Tags: swift, xcode

I have looked at similar problems on stack overflow and google, however my problem is not solved. I designed an app which uses a page scroll view in the Main.storyboard, which scrolls horizontally between other storyboards[pages]. I used the video [Snapchat-Like Menu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_daE3IL_1s) by Jared Davidson to help me.

Before, It was in the center, as I would expect it to. I think it changed when I updated to Xcode 8(But am not certain). However, everything is to the right. I think it changed when I updated to Xcode 8(But am not certain) I have tried updating the frames but it has been unsuccessful. Attached are some images to help show you the problem as well as my ViewController code.

What could I do?

Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

```
    //
//  ViewController.swift
//  
//
//  Created by Lucas Farleigh on 13/08/2016.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var MyScrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //Declaring the child views
        let VM : TitlePageViewController = TitlePageViewController(nibName: "TitlePageViewController", bundle: nil)
        let V1 : View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)
        let V2 : View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)
        let V3 : View3 = View3(nibName: "View3", bundle: nil)
        let V4 : View4 = View4(nibName: "View4", bundle: nil)
        let V5 : View5 = View5(nibName: "View5", bundle: nil)
        let V6 : View6 = View6(nibName: "View6", bundle: nil)
        let V7 : View7 = View7(nibName: "View7", bundle: nil)
        let V8 : View8 = View8(nibName: "View8", bundle: nil)
        let V9 : View9 = View9(nibName: "View9", bundle: nil)
        let V10 : View10 = View10(nibName: "View10", bundle: nil)
        let V11 : View11 = View11(nibName: "View11", bundle: nil)
        let V12 : View12 = View12(nibName: "View12", bundle: nil)
        let V13 : View13 = View13(nibName: "View13", bundle: nil)
        let V14 : View14 = View14(nibName: "View14", bundle: nil)
        let V15 : View15 = View15(nibName: "View15", bundle: nil)
        let V16 : View16 = View16(nibName: "View16", bundle: nil)
        let V17 : View17 = View17(nibName: "View17", bundle: nil)
        let V18 : View18 = View18(nibName: "View18", bundle: nil)
        let V19 : View19 = View19(nibName: "View19", bundle: nil)
        let V20 : View20 = View20(nibName: "View20", bundle: nil)
        let V21 : View21 = View21(nibName: "View21", bundle: nil)
        let V22 : View22 = View22(nibName: "View22", bundle: nil)
        let V23 : View23 = View23(nibName: "View23", bundle: nil)
        let V24 : View24 = View24(nibName: "View24", bundle: nil)
        let V25 : View25 = View25(nibName: "View25", bundle: nil)
        let V26 : View26 = View26(nibName: "View26", bundle: nil)
        let V27 : View27 = View27(nibName: "View27", bundle: nil)
        let V28 : View28 = View28(nibName: "View28", bundle: nil)
        let V29 : View29 = View29(nibName: "View29", bundle: nil)
        let V30 : View30 = View30(nibName: "View30", bundle: nil)
        let V31 : View31 = View31(nibName: "View31", bundle: nil)
        let V32 : View32 = View32(nibName: "View32", bundle: nil)
        let V33 : View33 = View33(nibName: "View33", bundle: nil)
        let V34 : View34 = View34(nibName: "View34", bundle: nil)
        let V35 : View35 = View35(nibName: "View35", bundle: nil)
        let V36 : View36 = View36(nibName: "View36", bundle: nil)
        let V37 : View37 = View37(nibName: "View37", bundle: nil)
        let V38 : View38 = View38(nibName: "View38", bundle: nil)
        let V39 : View39 = View39(nibName: "View39", bundle: nil)
        let V40 : View40 = View40(nibName: "View40", bundle: nil)
        let V41 : View39 = View39(nibName: "View41", bundle: nil)
        let V42 : View40 = View40(nibName: "View42", bundle: nil)

        //Decraling that the child views are child views
        self.addChildViewController(VM)
        self.addChildViewController(V1)
        self.addChildViewController(V2)
        self.addChildViewController(V3)
        self.addChildViewController(V4)
        self.addChildViewController(V5)
        self.addChildViewController(V6)
        self.addChildViewController(V7)
        self.addChildViewController(V8)
        self.addChildViewController(V9)
        self.addChildViewController(V10)
        self.addChildViewController(V11)
        self.addChildViewController(V12)
        self.addChildViewController(V13)
        self.addChildViewController(V14)
        self.addChildViewController(V15)
        self.addChildViewController(V16)
        self.addChildViewController(V17)
        self.addChildViewController(V18)
        self.addChildViewController(V19)
        self.addChildViewController(V20)
        self.addChildViewController(V21)
        self.addChildViewController(V22)
        self.addChildViewController(V23)
        self.addChildViewController(V24)
        self.addChildViewController(V25)
        self.addChildViewController(V26)
        self.addChildViewController(V27)
        self.addChildViewController(V28)
        self.addChildViewController(V29)
        self.addChildViewController(V30)
        self.addChildViewController(V31)
        self.addChildViewController(V32)
        self.addChildViewController(V33)
        self.addChildViewController(V34)
        self.addChildViewController(V35)
        self.addChildViewController(V36)
        self.addChildViewController(V37)
        self.addChildViewController(V38)
        self.addChildViewController(V39)
        self.addChildViewController(V40)
        self.addChildViewController(V41)
        self.addChildViewController(V42)


        //Adding the view into the scrollview (MyScrollView)
   /**/ self.MyScrollView.addSubview(VM.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V2.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V3.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V4.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V5.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V6.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V7.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V8.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V9.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V10.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V11.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V12.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V13.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V14.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V15.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V16.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V17.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V18.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V19.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V20.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V21.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V22.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V23.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V24.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V25.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V26.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V27.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V28.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V29.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V30.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V31.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V32.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V33.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V34.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V35.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V36.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V37.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V38.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V39.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V40.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V41.view)
        self.MyScrollView.addSubview(V42.view)

        //Confirming that it did move to the view controller
 /**/   VM.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V3.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V4.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V5.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V6.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V7.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V8.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V9.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V10.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V11.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V12.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V13.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V14.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V15.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V16.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V17.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V18.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V19.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V20.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V21.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V22.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V23.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V24.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V25.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V26.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V27.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V28.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V29.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V30.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V31.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V32.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V33.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V34.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V35.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V36.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V37.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V38.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V39.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V40.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V41.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        V42.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        //SIZES AND POSITIONS

        //Declaring how big the scroll view is
        self.MyScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 43, height: self.view.frame.height)

        //Setting the frame of the Views
        var V1Frame : CGRect = V1.view.frame
        var V2Frame : CGRect = V2.view.frame
        var V3Frame : CGRect = V3.view.frame
        var V4Frame : CGRect = V4.view.frame
        var V5Frame : CGRect = V5.view.frame
        var V6Frame : CGRect = V6.view.frame
        var V7Frame : CGRect = V7.view.frame
        var V8Frame : CGRect = V8.view.frame
        var V9Frame : CGRect = V9.view.frame
        var V10Frame : CGRect = V10.view.frame
        var V11Frame : CGRect = V11.view.frame
        var V12Frame : CGRect = V12.view.frame
        var V13Frame : CGRect = V13.view.frame
        var V14Frame : CGRect = V14.view.frame
        var V15Frame : CGRect = V15.view.frame
        var V16Frame : CGRect = V16.view.frame
        var V17Frame : CGRect = V17.view.frame
        var V18Frame : CGRect = V18.view.frame
        var V19Frame : CGRect = V19.view.frame
        var V20Frame : CGRect = V20.view.frame
        var V21Frame : CGRect = V21.view.frame
        var V22Frame : CGRect = V22.view.frame
        var V23Frame : CGRect = V23.view.frame
        var V24Frame : CGRect = V24.view.frame
        var V25Frame : CGRect = V25.view.frame
        var V26Frame : CGRect = V26.view.frame
        var V27Frame : CGRect = V27.view.frame
        var V28Frame : CGRect = V28.view.frame
        var V29Frame : CGRect = V29.view.frame
        var V30Frame : CGRect = V30.view.frame
        var V31Frame : CGRect = V31.view.frame
        var V32Frame : CGRect = V32.view.frame
        var V33Frame : CGRect = V33.view.frame
        var V34Frame : CGRect = V34.view.frame
        var V35Frame : CGRect = V35.view.frame
        var V36Frame : CGRect = V36.view.frame
        var V37Frame : CGRect = V37.view.frame
        var V38Frame : CGRect = V38.view.frame
        var V39Frame : CGRect = V39.view.frame
        var V40Frame : CGRect = V40.view.frame
        var V41Frame : CGRect = V41.view.frame
        var V42Frame : CGRect = V42.view.frame

        //Making it off the screen to the right
        V1Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        V2Frame.origin.x = 2 * self.view.frame.width
        V3Frame.origin.x = 3 * self.view.frame.width
        V4Frame.origin.x = 4 * self.view.frame.width
        V5Frame.origin.x = 5 * self.view.frame.width
        V6Frame.origin.x = 6 * self.view.frame.width
        V7Frame.origin.x = 7 * self.view.frame.width
        V8Frame.origin.x = 8 * self.view.frame.width
        V9Frame.origin.x = 9 * self.view.frame.width
        V10Frame.origin.x = 10 * self.view.frame.width
        V11Frame.origin.x = 11 * self.view.frame.width
        V12Frame.origin.x = 12 * self.view.frame.width
        V13Frame.origin.x = 13 * self.view.frame.width
        V14Frame.origin.x = 14 * self.view.frame.width
        V15Frame.origin.x = 15 * self.view.frame.width
        V16Frame.origin.x = 16 * self.view.frame.width
        V17Frame.origin.x = 17 * self.view.frame.width
        V18Frame.origin.x = 18 * self.view.frame.width
        V19Frame.origin.x = 19 * self.view.frame.width
        V20Frame.origin.x = 20 * self.view.frame.width
        V21Frame.origin.x = 21 * self.view.frame.width
        V22Frame.origin.x = 22 * self.view.frame.width
        V23Frame.origin.x = 23 * self.view.frame.width
        V24Frame.origin.x = 24 * self.view.frame.width
        V25Frame.origin.x = 25 * self.view.frame.width
        V26Frame.origin.x = 26 * self.view.frame.width
        V27Frame.origin.x = 27 * self.view.frame.width
        V28Frame.origin.x = 28 * self.view.frame.width
        V29Frame.origin.x = 29 * self.view.frame.width
        V30Frame.origin.x = 30 * self.view.frame.width
        V31Frame.origin.x = 31 * self.view.frame.width
        V32Frame.origin.x = 32 * self.view.frame.width
        V33Frame.origin.x = 33 * self.view.frame.width
        V34Frame.origin.x = 34 * self.view.frame.width
        V35Frame.origin.x = 35 * self.view.frame.width
        V36Frame.origin.x = 36 * self.view.frame.width
        V37Frame.origin.x = 37 * self.view.frame.width
        V38Frame.origin.x = 38 * self.view.frame.width
        V39Frame.origin.x = 39 * self.view.frame.width
        V40Frame.origin.x = 40 * self.view.frame.width
        V41Frame.origin.x = 41 * self.view.frame.width
        V42Frame.origin.x = 42 * self.view.frame.width

        //Adding it on to the view
        V1.view.frame = V1Frame
        V2.view.frame = V2Frame
        V3.view.frame = V3Frame
        V4.view.frame = V4Frame
        V5.view.frame = V5Frame
        V6.view.frame = V6Frame
        V7.view.frame = V7Frame
        V8.view.frame = V8Frame
        V9.view.frame = V9Frame
        V10.view.frame = V10Frame
        V11.view.frame = V11Frame
        V12.view.frame = V12Frame
        V13.view.frame = V13Frame
        V14.view.frame = V14Frame
        V15.view.frame = V15Frame
        V16.view.frame = V16Frame
        V17.view.frame = V17Frame
        V18.view.frame = V18Frame
        V19.view.frame = V19Frame
        V20.view.frame = V20Frame
        V21.view.frame = V21Frame
        V22.view.frame = V22Frame
        V23.view.frame = V23Frame
        V24.view.frame = V24Frame
        V25.view.frame = V25Frame
        V26.view.frame = V26Frame
        V27.view.frame = V27Frame
        V28.view.frame = V28Frame
        V29.view.frame = V29Frame
        V30.view.frame = V30Frame
        V31.view.frame = V31Frame
        V32.view.frame = V32Frame
        V33.view.frame = V33Frame
        V34.view.frame = V34Frame
        V35.view.frame = V35Frame
        V36.view.frame = V36Frame
        V37.view.frame = V37Frame
        V38.view.frame = V38Frame
        V39.view.frame = V39Frame
        V40.view.frame = V40Frame
        V41.view.frame = V41Frame
        V42.view.frame = V42Frame


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? That'd be my first guess. Unfortunately without seeing your code, it's very difficult to diagnose.

Comment: I will add the code

Comment: There is no need to add "Swift Xcode 8" to the title, you already included those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but what you're doing is totally wrong and you need to abandon it. 42 view controllers with 42 screen-sized views, all of them in the scroll view at the same time, is just bad practice.

Switch to using UIPageViewController. It is a paged horizontal scroller, it does what you're trying to do, and it does it efficiently — only one view controller and one view exists at any one moment.